# SQL Stored Procedure - revise code

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have this code for a stored procedure. It executes in approx 4 minutes, which is good, but my question is that in the way it was created it is doing only drop and recreate the table, but I would like it to delete a range of records, process them again from the source and insert the update values in the table.

The code is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [BW].[InventoryBalance_EndingBalance]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    --DROP TABLE DataWhs.dbo.InventoryBalancesEnd   
    DELETE DataWhs.dbo.InventoryBalancesEnd
    WHERE Period > (YEAR(GETDATE())-1)*100 + MONTH(GETDATE())+8


    SELECT DISTINCT 
        C.Period, ib.Account, ib.SalesOrg, IB.ProfitCenter, 
        IB.ValueType, IB.Plant, ib.SubscriptionKey
    INTO #Tempib6
    FROM 
        DataWhs.dbo.InventoryBalances ib
    CROSS JOIN
        DataWhs.Dates.Cumulated c
    WHERE 
        c.Period <= YEAR(GETDATE())*100 + MONTH(GETDATE())

    ALTER TABLE #Tempib6
    ADD [Amount_LC_EndBal] [numeric](18, 2), 
        [Amount_GC_EndBal] [numeric](18, 2);

    UPDATE T1 
    SET T1.Amount_LC_EndBal = (SELECT SUM(T2.Amount_LC)
                                FROM DataWhs.dbo.InventoryBalances T2 
                                WHERE T2.Period <= T1.Period 
                                  AND T1.Period NOT LIKE '%00' 
                                  AND T2.Period NOT LIKE '%00'
                                  AND T1.Account = T2.Account
                                  AND T1.ProfitCenter = T2.ProfitCenter
                                  AND T1.SalesOrg = T2.SalesOrg
                                  AND T1.ValueType = T2.ValueType
                                  AND T1.Plant = T2.Plant),
        T1.Amount_GC_EndBal = (SELECT SUM(T2.Amount_GC) 
                               FROM DataWhs.dbo.InventoryBalances T2 
                               WHERE T2.Period <= T1.Period 
                                 AND T1.Period NOT LIKE '%00' 
                                 AND T2.Period NOT LIKE '%00'
                                 AND T1.Account = T2.Account
                                 AND T1.ProfitCenter = T2.ProfitCenter
                                 AND T1.SalesOrg = T2.SalesOrg
                                 AND T1.ValueType = T2.ValueType
                                 AND T1.Plant = T2.Plant)
    FROM #Tempib6 T1;

    SELECT * 
    INTO dbo.InventoryBalancesEnd 
    FROM #Tempib6
    WHERE 
         #Tempib6.Amount_LC_EndBal IS NOT NULL 
         AND #Tempib6.Amount_LC_EndBal <> 0
         --(to remove comment after first full load) and #Tempib6.Period > 
         --(YEAR(GETDATE())-1)*100 + MONTH(GETDATE())+8

    DROP TABLE #Tempib6
END
```

Thanks

Comment: thats not a question even though you call it one.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: It is SQL Server, my question is that this code might need some adjustments because I built but I am not expert on the subject. Randall Mathews gave already very good hints. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1 reputation shy of making this a comment. I'm guessing the reason for the current code deleting everything is that it's much more efficient to trunc a table, than it is to do a partial delete.

With that said there is something that jumps out at me from your delete logic in the above;

```
DELETE DataWhs.dbo.InventoryBalancesEnd
WHERE Period > (YEAR(GETDATE())-1)*100 + MONTH(GETDATE())+8
```

So you are deleting anything that's newer than 4 months ago, at least I think that's the intention (-1 year +8 months). However that's not a mathematically sound way to do that, if the current month is may or later, you'll end up values like 1413, which would be an invalid year month combination. Try the below:

```
Declare @dateDelete datetime = (Select dateadd(month, -4, getdate()))
Declare @intFirstPeriod int = (select (YEAR(@dateDelete))*100 + MONTH(@dateDelete))
declare @intCurrentPeriod int = (select (YEAR(Getdate()))*100 + MONTH(@GetDate))
DELETE DataWhs.dbo.InventoryBalancesEnd
WHERE Period > @intFirstPeriod
```

There is also another part you need to change to avoid duplication, your first select into query, gets anything less than or equal to the current period, which could duplicate anything older than 4 months. Also your using functions in a where clause, which forces a table scan, you can avoid this by pre-calculating the values like I do in the above variables. Using those same variables in the first select into:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  C.Period, ib.Account, ib.SalesOrg, IB.ProfitCenter, IB.ValueType, IB.Plant, ib.SubscriptionKey
INTO #Tempib6
FROM 
  DataWhs.dbo.InventoryBalances ib
CROSS JOIN
  DataWhs.Dates.Cumulated c
WHERE c.Period between @intFirstPeriod and @intCurrentPeriod
```

That's about all the issues I can see currently, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Thank you very much, Randall Mathews